# playTone function of Buzzer

Tags: arduino-uno, buzzer

I am making "Simon says" game using Arduino on TinkerCad.
I am facing issue in Buzzer sound function.
I want something like this:

1. Use the following steps to generate the tone for the red LED:
   Play 440 Hz for 150ms
   Wait for 1136us
   Play 440 Hz for 150ms
2. Use the following steps to generate the tone for the yellow LED:
   Play 784 Hz for 150ms
   Wait for 638us
   Play 784 Hz for 150ms
3. Use the following steps to generate the tone for the blue LED:
   Play 587 Hz for 150ms
   Wait for 851us
   Play 587 Hz for 150ms
4. Use the following steps to generate the tone for the green LED:
   Play 880 Hz for 150ms
   Wait for 568us
   Play 880 Hz for 150ms

I have following functions for the above:

```
 void playTone2(int tone, int duration) {
  Serial.println(tone);
  for (long i = 0; i < duration * 1000L; i += tone * 2) {
    digitalWriteGeneric(buzzer, true);
    delayMicroseconds(tone);
    digitalWriteGeneric(buzzer, false);
    delayMicroseconds(tone);
  }
}

void playTone(int tone1) {
  Serial.println(tone1);
  if (tone1 == 440) {
    playTone2(440, 150);
    delayMicroseconds(1136);
    playTone2(440, 150);
  }
  if (tone1 == 784) {
    playTone2(784, 150);
    delayMicroseconds(638);
    playTone2(784, 150);
  }
  if (tone1 == 587) {
    playTone2(587, 150);
    delayMicroseconds(851);
    playTone2(587, 150);
  }
  if (tone1 == 880) {
    playTone2(880, 150);
    delayMicroseconds(568);
    playTone2(880, 150);
  }
  if (tone1 == 2700) {
    playTone2(250, 250);
    delay(250);
    playTone2(150, 250);
  }

}
```

First there was only playTone code but I needed different values for different LEDs so I included playTone function and called playTone2 to it.
But the tones that I am getting are not accurate may be because of two functions. I will be able to resolve it if I could understand the working of playTone2 function. I tried but no use, kindly share how exactly playtone2 functions here so that I can edit my playTone function accordingly.

Comment: what's the specific problem? ... all you said is `facing issue` and `not accurate`, neither of which describe the actual problem

Comment: The problem is that the Buzzer sound with these functions is not accurate the delay is longer than expected.

Comment: you already said  `not accurate`

Comment: please run a simple sketch that plays the scale

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple sketch to test the tones used for each color of LED. I have not tested it with a speaker, but it compiles in the Arduino IDE, so perhaps it will work as is.

The call to `delayMicroseconds()` is "blocking" code, so you may want to change it to use "non-blocking" code, e.g. Use the `BlinkWithoutDelay` example in the IDE to make a `micros()` based timer.

```c++
/* Arduino Uno. IDE 1.8.9
   Sketch uses 2540 bytes (7%) of program storage space.
   Global variables use 28 bytes (1%) of dynamic memory.

   red    LED: Play 440 Hz for 150ms Wait for 1136us Play 440 Hz for 150ms
   yellow LED: Play 784 Hz for 150ms Wait for 638us Play 784 Hz for 150ms
   blue   LED: Play 587 Hz for 150ms Wait for 851us Play 587 Hz for 150ms
   green  LED: Play 880 Hz for 150ms Wait for 568us Play 880 Hz for 150ms
*/
byte tonePin = 8;

void setup(){
  pinMode(tonePin, OUTPUT);
  RedLEDSound();
  YellowLEDSound();
  BlueLEDSound();
  GreenLEDSound();
}

void loop(){}

void PlayTone(unsigned int m_frequency, unsigned long m_duration, unsigned long m_pause){
  tone(tonePin, m_frequency, m_duration);
  delayMicroseconds(m_pause);
  noTone(tonePin);
}

void RedLEDSound(){
  PlayTone(440, 150, 1136);
  PlayTone(440, 150, 0);
}

void YellowLEDSound(){
  PlayTone(784, 150, 638);
  PlayTone(784, 150, 0);
}

void BlueLEDSound(){
  PlayTone(587, 150, 851);
  PlayTone(587, 150, 0);
}

void GreenLEDSound(){
  PlayTone(880, 150, 568);
  PlayTone(880, 150, 0);
}
```